# React & react-native monorepo: Issue with node_module imports

Tags: reactjs, react-native, node-modules, yarn-workspaces, metro-bundler

I have set up a monorepo with yarn workspaces housing a react & react-native app. This is is the structure:

```
├── package.json
├── packages
│   ├── shared
│   │   ├── package.json
│   │   └── components
│   ├── mobile
│   │   ├── android
│   │   ├── ios
│   │   ├── package.json
│   │   ├── src
│   │   ├── tests
│   │   └── yarn.lock
│   └── web
│       ├── public
│       ├── src
│       └── package.json
└── yarn.lock
```

In order to share logic between both apps, presentational components are wrapped in a `ExampleComponentContainer.js` which imports `ExampleComponent.native.js` or `ExampleComponent.js`, depending on the bundler. I added redux and react-redux to the shared packages' `package.json` and import them in ExampleComponentContainer.js and both apps' entrypoints App.js. While webpack has no issues importing the modules from the root node_modules folder, metro only picks the up for the react-native app if i specify them as

```
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from '../../../../node_modules/react-redux/dist/react-redux';
```

just using

```
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux';
```

doesnt work. This is the error im getting:

[iOS error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWStN.png)

This is my metro.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  projectRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../'),
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: false,
      },
    }),
  },
};
```

Thanks for any hints how to solve this.